# Extracting the first decimal value between XML tags

Tags: regex, xml, perl, notepad++, pcre

`<value>1.1111/1.22222</value>`

Here I need to extract *only* the first value `1.1111` that is between `<value>` and the `/` in `1.1111/1.22222`.

Can anyone suggest how to solve this issue?

Note that I am trying to make this work in a monitoring tool that uses Perl regex syntax, and I am testing in Notepad++.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try the following PCRE regex:

```
(?<=<value>)(\d+\.\d+)(?=\/)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/GUrJKWfu0OAph5xK) (with the sample input string in the question)

Key points:

- `(?<=\<value\>)` – a positive look*behind* (`(?<=`...`)`) for `<value>` – i.e. that `<value>` precedes the next portion of the input string to match
- `(\d+\.\d+)` – a decimal number in the form of one or more (`+`) digits (`\d`), a period (`\.`), and one or more digits again
- `(?=\/)` – a positive look*ahead* (`(?=`...`)`) for `/` – i.e. *that* `/` follows

I confirmed that it works in Notepad++ (per the comment on sputnick's answer)...

[image: Confirmation in Notepad++]

..., but experimentation revealed that *[the lookbehind appears to be worthless in Notepad++](http://benmearns.blogspot.com/2011/08/lookbehindlookahead-assertion-with-npp.html)* (i.e. does not make a difference, the match being performed by the rest of the pattern): basically, *your mileage may vary testing this with Notepad++*.

Comment: Actually it gives `<value>1.1111/` but i am only interested in 1.1111 :(

Comment: @kumar: Yes and no. It matches `1.1111` in the capture group (i.e. between `(` and `)`. I think I see your dilema now, though (i.e. that you cannot use a capture group's value since you are not doing this programmatically but through a tool). I will chew on that a bit and edit with an update.

Comment: err, surely you want a positive lookbehind?

Comment: @ysth: Der, der, der. Yes, there was a disconnect between the pattern I presented at the outset of my answer and in the screenshot (which used a positive lookbehind)...and what I explained under "Key points" (wherein I indicated a negative lookbehind). Thanks for catching that. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: a perl positive lookbehind starts `(?<=`

Comment: Yes, I noticed that syntax flub and tracked it down to Notepad++...not really even paying attention to the lookbehind – hence, not catching that syntax flub (and not being a very good way to test this): I already updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thx a lot guys, the issue is resolved with J0e3gan's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Using [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) and [xmllint](/questions/tagged/xmllint) :

```
//value/text()
```

Demo in a shell :

```
$ echo '<value>1.1111/1.22222</value>'| xmllint --xpath '//value/text()' - |
    cut -d '/' -f1
```

Comment: Hi sputnick, thanks for the quick reply. Actually i need to get the value 1.1111 between `"<value"` and "/" by using PERL supported RegEX pattern in an application. how to do this?

Comment: Actually i am using a monitoring tool which supports PERL RegEX, i am not directly trying this on any *nix platforms. I am just trying to accomplish this on the Notepad++ which supports perl RegEX..

Answer (score 0):

As a perl regex:

```
/<value>\K(?a:\d+\.\d+)(?=\/)/
```

but if your actual case doesn't support all those features of perl, you may need:

```
/(?<=<value>)([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)(?=\/)/
```